# Odoo / Postgres: Concatenate rows value until condition = true

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, odoo-8

I'm creating a new view for a customized PoS module for my restaurant. It's a specific view for kitchen, already filtered to show just kitchen's related items of a PoS order.
Now I would like to show a particular series of product with the name starting with "#" in a field populated by a function side by side with the "standard" products. In fact I'm speaking of a set of instructions coded as products to be available on PoS and to suit my needs I decided to create kitchen instructions as a product (service). In my PoS there are 3 categories that are not products but instructions (ADD, SUBTRACT, ADDITIONAL NOTE).

A typical order will show as:

```
Product                    Quantity 
[1007] Pom. Secchi                1
# + Búfala                        1
# - Mussarela                     1
[2002] Nutella banana             1
# + Mussarela                     1
```

What I would like to archive is a view like:

```
Product                  Note                        Quantity 
[1007] Pom. Secchi       # + Búfala # - Mussarela           1
[2002] Nutella banana    # + Mussarela                      1
```

I need to select just the strings starting with the "#" between two internal code starting with "[code]" and this is the hard thing to do. I don't need to delete the values I "move" because I need the stock view when I print the receipt.
I will call this function using python (and psycopg2 on postgresql 9.4) with on_change or extending the workflow when an order is marked as "paid". I don't think if doing it directly in Python is viable.
I've tried with

```
string_agg(,)
```

but with bad results.
 
Any tips about what should be the correct path to start coding? Thanks.

Comment: Now can we please have the "homework" tag back, again?

Comment: I don't know if I well understood what do you mean. I'm not asking to write code for me. I'm simply asking what is the best approach because isn't a simple task to accomplish and I'm not an expert in Python or Postgres. I'm here to learn and the search did show nothing similar (odoo+postgres).